# Question with Iptable rules

Tags: networking, ubuntu, iptables

I want to block the packets whose source ip is not localhost(172.17.7.1) when sending out. how to do this ?  I write a rule like this

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -s !172.17.7.1 -J DROP
```

it does not work`

Comment: Why are you saying that `172.17.7.1` is localhost? Localhost is the subnet `127./8`, and only it.

Comment: 172.17.7.1 is the gateway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iptables -A OUTPUT -s ! 172.17.7.1 -j DROP

Use small caps "j" and append space after "!" sign, else it will be interpreted like a command from your shell history.
Pay attention that you do apppend with A and not insert on the beginning of the chain.

Comment: thanks! can i add more conditions? for instance, block all the packets whose source ip is not localhost(172.17.7.1) and 58.30.30.3

Comment: For every one additional IP address you must use another rule. But you can use IP/mask syntax to get few addresses if they are at the same range. Dropping all the output traffic you are at risk, for example to drop your server DNS query or any other traffic that is needed for normal use. Do not use term like localhost for IP addresses assigned to your network card.

Comment: ntk, you are very nice, could you check this question out /? http://serverfault.com/questions/203324/how-to-forward-packets-from-ppp-interface